# Include Watir test cases in a Continuous Integration system

Tags: testcase, continuous-integration, watir, hudson

Did anyone succeed deploying Watir test cases to a continuous integration system such as Team City or Hudson?

> I'm trying to find a way to have the test scripts executed and have the results generated in a report format? Any experiences using the Ruby plugin for Hudson plus the ci_reporter?

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google shows plenty of people doing this, including [This page from WatirMelon](http://watirmelon.com/2010/11/04/running-watir-reliably-on-a-ci-machine/) ( if you dont know of this site could be worth your while reading it, lots of good stuff on it )

and an example of using ci_reporter is [here](http://pastebin.com/KueD466k)

Comment: Thanks for you answer but the first link just talks about some tricks to avoid the execution being interrupted and in the second link the text seems to be truncated.

Comment: Link works for me and all the text is there, link is http://pastebin.com/KueD466k   Maybe you could expand more on exactly what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

I am running Watir scripts from Jenkins CI on a couple of projects. I do plan to write about it at my blog soon. If you have specific questions, please ask. I have recently recorded a screencast about the entire test automation solution I have developed for a client: [Test automation at HomeSwap.com](http://filipin.eu/test-automation-at-homeswap-com/)

Comment: I've used Jenkins but I don't think I've used Jenkins CI. Any idea what's the difference between them?

Comment: As far as I know, it's the same thing. :)