# Regarding running Watir scripts for UI Automation from Jenkins CI - How to hook up Jenkins and watir-automations

Tags: jenkins, ruby, watir-webdriver

I already have Watir-Ruby scripts running on a macintosh which uses Firefox as the browser to run the automation.

I have been given a linux server where the Jenkins build is going on. I got to put my scripts in that server and the automation needs to kick off once the build is done. Will Jenkins on linux be able to trigger UI Automation on a macintosh or will the UI Automation run on the linux machine?

Comment: We need more information to give you a good answer: What have you tried? Where have you looked?

Comment: I think same question has already been asked at SQA SE. Please refer to this link  http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3474/include-watir-test-cases-in-a-continuous-integration-system

Comment: I did went through that links. Its for hooking up hudson and Watir not Jenkins.

Comment: [link](http://filipin.eu/test-automation-at-homeswap-com/) mentioned in there does not exists

Comment: Hudson and Jenkins are nearly identical. Jenkins split up from Hudson some years ago, but the foundation is the same and they work very similar.

Answer (score 1):

There are two directions you can take if you want to run the UI test on a Mac with Jenkins:

- Setup a Jenkins slave on the Mac and execute all Jenkins steps on that node. Example blog post: https://blog.samsaodev.com/how-to-setup-a-jenkins-slave-running-mac-osx-for-ios-projects-part-1/
- Setup a Selenium Webdriver grid and let Jenkins run the tests on the Mac grid node: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2

But Linux can run Firefox WebDriver tests just fine, question if they really need to run on the Mac :)

Maybe aslso read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685928/selenium-grid-with-cucumber